# Django time based query set giving unexpected response

Tags: python, django

I have a table as follows:

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    arena = models.ForeignKey(Arena, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    token = UUIDField(auto=True, unique=True, null=True)
    validity = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Now I'm using it in a django view as follows:

```
def post(self, request):
    data = request.DATA
    arena = data['arena']
    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['start_time'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['end_time'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    try:
        slots = Availability.objects.filter(Q(arena__id=arena), Q(start_date__gte=start_time), Q(end_date__lte=end_time)) #Checking if there's any availability between a certain period of time at a certain arena            
        serialized = ScheduleSerializer(slots, many=True)
        return Response({
            'success': False,
            'response': serialized.data #empty array
        })
    except Availability.DoesNotExist:
        ... #Some Code
```

I have no objects in my Availability table yet the above query gets executed and returns an empty array as the response. Is my query correct? If not, how do I fix this?

Comment: Tha's how `filter` works; it returns a queryset, which can be empty if it finds no matches. `get` raises `DoesNotExist`, but it's for fetching one instance. You can check `len` of slots and if it's empty, then apply whatever condition you want to apply.

Comment: We can also use `.exists()` to check if it is empty. We can raise the DoesNotExist error or another error there if needed. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working as expected. You are doing a query and no objects are found that match the query (because there are no objects). Try something like this:

```
slots = Availability.objects.filter(Q(arena__id=arena), Q(start_date__gte=start_time), Q(end_date__lte=end_time)) #Checking if there's any availability between a certain period of time at a certain arena

if slots:            
    serialized = ScheduleSerializer(slots, many=True)
    return Response({
        'success': False,
        'response': serialized.data #empty array
    })
else:
    ...
```